# systemd exits create-react-app

Tags: systemd, services, node.js

I am trying to use a systemd service to run a Node app (specifically, a React app generated with create-react-app.  I put a file `frontend.service` at `/etc/systemd/system/` with (minimally) these contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=React Web Application

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/npm start --prefix=<path to app>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After starting the service, my browser shows the nginx `bad gateway` error, and `ps aux | grep node` shows no corresponding process.  The output of `journalctl -u frontend` reports successful steps like "Started React Web Application" and eventually "Starting development server...".  However, `systemctl status frontend` reports that the service is loaded but inactive/dead (edit: or, active/exited).

I tried some adjustments to the `.service` file, in particular `Type=forking`, `RemainAfterExit=true`, and `KillMode=process`.  But the problem persists.  What is going on?  How to fix this?

The app does work fine if I run it directly using `npm start` in the shell.  Also, another (non-node) web server works fine running through a similar systemd script.

Here is the systemctl status output:

```
wm-frontend.service - React Web Application
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wm-frontend.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2020-08-10 14:40:59 UTC; 32min ago
  Process: 4033 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/npm start --prefix=/home/mw/wm-ax/frontend/blog --scripts-prepend-node-path (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4033 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 10 14:40:59 localhost systemd[1]: Started React Web Application.
Aug 10 14:41:00 localhost npm[4033]: > blog@0.1.0 start /home/mw/wm-ax/frontend/blog
Aug 10 14:41:00 localhost npm[4033]: > react-scripts start
Aug 10 14:41:04 localhost npm[4033]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:3000/
Aug 10 14:41:04 localhost npm[4033]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
Aug 10 14:41:04 localhost npm[4033]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /home/mw/wm-ax/frontend/blog/public
Aug 10 14:41:04 localhost npm[4033]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Aug 10 14:41:04 localhost npm[4033]: Starting the development server...
```

Comment: When you run it by hand in the shell does it stay in the foreground?

Comment: Yes, `npm start` leaves a process running in the foreground.

Comment: One possible explanation might be that `npm start` issues a fork at some point (could there be distinct `build` and `serve` processes?), and that systemd stops the child process once `build` returns.

Comment: I'm thinking environment variable.  What happens if you run `env -i /usr/local/bin/npm start`?  If that has a problem, then figure out which environment variable your application needs and set it in your service file.

Comment: Interesting thought!  When prefixed by `env -i`, the `npm start` command fails, with `~/.npm/_log` file suggesting the flag `--scripts-prepend-node-path`.  This flag does allow `npm start` to run from an empty environment.  However, the result of adding the flag to the `ExecStart` entry of the systemd script still doesn't work:(.

Comment: The systemctl status logs seem to indicate that the systemd failure happens later than the failure introduced with `env -i`: specifically, the systemd execution logs include the line `starting the development server...` while the missing node-path environment variable causes a failure just after an earlier message `react-scripts start`.

Comment: In interactive execution which user is used?

Comment: The problem *might* be that `npm start` spawns a new shell..

Comment: In interactive execution, `npm start` is used with the usual local user account.

Comment: @SirMuffington - that seems plausible, since `npm start` in successful execution seems to spawn a new foreground process just after emitting "Starting development server..."; and this is the last message recorded in the systemctl log files.

Comment: @Krackout interactive execution is ok also with e.g. `sudo -u www-data npm start`

Comment: The user could be the problem in conjuction with env. So you execute `npm start` either using a local user (other than root I suppose) or `www-data`. The systemd service tries to start using `root`, even if root is not enabled, sudo only system. Of course root has the power to start whatever service, but the env is different. Give it a try if you like, you'll find many articles on how to start a systemd service using a specific user.

Comment: @Krackout as noted above, `npm start` does run successfully with an empty environment, so it's not clear how difference of environment should cause a problem.  Adding `User=www-data` and `Group=www-data` to the service file also doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1011435/584430), as of February 2020 the `start.js` process is [stipulated to exit](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/commit/7e6d6cd05f3054723c8b015c813e13761659759e#diff-d231b8cdf8c6b73068083e851c3a7c5bR168-R175) when it reaches the end of `stdin`.  When the process is run non-interactively (as by a systemd service), the end of `stdin` is immediate, and so the script terminates as described above.

Comment: Curious, was there an argument you had to pass to make `IsInteractive` false?  Or did you have to set `StandardInput=`?

Comment: In the `start.js` script, that constant is set using the Node `process` api, with `const isInteractive = process.stdout.isTTY`.